# How to evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\{(n+1)^{1/3}-n^{1/3}\}?$

Tags: real-analysis

How to calculate $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\{(n+1)^{1/3}-n^{1/3}\}?$$

Of course it's a sequence of positive reals but I can't proceed any further.

Comment: Just use binomial th for reals, goes to $0$.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** multiply by $\frac{(n+1)^{2/3}+(n+1)^{1/3}n^{1/3}+n^{2/3}}{(n+1)^{2/3}+(n+1)^{1/3}n^{1/3}+n^{2/3}}$ to get
$$
(n+1)^{1/3}-n^{1/3}=\frac{(n+1)-n}{(n+1)^{2/3}+(n+1)^{1/3}n^{1/3}+n^{2/3}}
$$

---

Alternatively, use the definition of the derivative:
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)^{1/3}-n^{1/3}}{(n+1)-n}
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{-2/3}\frac{(1+1/n)^{1/3}-1}{(1+1/n)-1}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{-2/3}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(1+1/n)^{1/3}-1}{(1+1/n)-1}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{-2/3}\left.\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}x^{1/3}\right|_{x=1}\\
&=0\cdot\frac13\\[8pt]
&=0
\end{align}
$$

---

I think the simplest method is to use the Mean Value Theorem
$$
(n+1)^{1/3}-n^{1/3}=\frac{(n+1)^{1/3}-n^{1/3}}{(n+1)-n}=\frac13\eta^{-2/3}
$$
for some $\eta\in(n,n+1)$.

Answer (score 5):

Use this well-known identity:

$$(a^3-b^3)=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$$

Answer (score 3):

Using $(1+x)^\alpha\sim_0 1+\alpha x$ we find

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(n+1)^{1/3}-n^{1/3}=\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{1/3}\left(\left(1+n^{-1}\right)^{1/3}-1\right)\\=\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{1/3}\left(1+\frac{1}{3}n^{-1}-1\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{3n^{2/3}}=0$$

Comment: lab, robjohn, B.S., and I deliberately did not take it to the end because the OP did not show very much work.

Comment: Again lovely $\sim_{\infty}$. :)

Answer (score 1):

First, take **@B.S.**'s suggestion. Let $u=(n+1)^{1/3}$ and $v=n^{1/3}$. Then, $$ (n+1) - n = u^3 - v^3 = (u-v) \cdot (u^2+v^2+uv) = 1. $$We want to find the limit as $n$ approches of $\infty$ of $u-v$. In other words, $$ \dfrac {1}{u^2+v^2+uv}. $$Now, look at the degrees of the numerator and denominator (or think in terms of l'Hospital's Rule if you have learned that already) and extrapolate the answer.

Comment: @amWhy: pray-tell, why? It is not like if you inserted the `@` mark there, B.S. would be notified. There's a reason that the mechanism is called "comment notification" and not "answer notification"! If anything, if you want to make an edit like this, please go all the way and actually include a link to the answer B.S. posted below.

Comment: Point taken @WillieWong. I'm not even sure why I edited. I think it was a knee-jerk reflex which I didn't think through. (And it puzzles me that I did edit (and trivially so), since I *rarely* edit other users' posts!) Apologies to Ahaan if the edit upset you. And, +1 Ahaan for a fine answer.

Comment: @amWhy It did not upset me at all. I like it when people make my posts look nice. And thanks for the +1!