# Evaluate $lim_{n \to \infty} (n + 1)^{\frac{2}{3}} - (n)^{\frac{2}{3}}$ using the generalized binomial theorem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, binomial-theorem

I have already checked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/583208/how-to-evaluate-lim-n-to-infty-n11-3-n1-3) and have understood the approaches using the Product Rule for Limits, and the one using the Mean Value Theorem.

I was wondering whether it is possible to evaluate this limit using the Binomial Theorem for Rational Exponents.

After expanding, we get :
$$ (n+1)^{\frac{2}{3}} - (n)^{\frac{2}{3}} = \frac{2}{3} \cdot \sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{n}} - \frac{1}{9} \cdot {n}^{\frac{-4}{3}} + \frac{4}{81} \cdot {n}^{\frac{-7}{3}} - \frac{7}{243} \cdot {n}^{\frac{-10}{3}} + \cdots \infty $$

I'm not sure how to rigorously prove that this series sum goes to $0$. Can you help me understand this? This is my first question on MSE so I apologise if I have violated any website rules. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you compare your expression to, say, some geometric series?

Comment: I'm not sure I see that. Is @lab-bhattacharjee's answer and my response to that, the argument you are referring to?

Comment: Not really. I was thinking of comparing your series to something like $$\frac23\sqrt[3]{\frac1n}\left(1-\frac1n+\frac1{n^2}-\frac1{n^3} + \cdots\right)$$

Comment: Ok. Perhaps I should mention that the terms which follow 
$\frac{-7}{243} \cdot n^{\frac{-7}{3}}$ 
are 
$\frac{14}{729} \cdot n^{\frac{-10}{3}}, \frac{-91}{6561} \cdot n^{\frac{-16}{3}}, \cdots $. 
I can't think of getting these terms in the form you suggested.

Comment: I'm not saying you should _get them_ on that form. I'm saying you should _compare them_ to that form. And I made a mistake: I shouldn't have alternated signs, they should've been $+$ all the way.

Answer (score 1):

Set $1/n=h$ to reach at $$\dfrac{(1+h)^{2/3}-1}{h^{2/3}}=?$$

Now use https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series

Comment: Ok so this becomes : 

$$
\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{(1+h)^{\frac{-1}{3}}}{h^{\frac{-1}{3}}}
$$

by L'Hospital's Rule, and then, by using the binomial series expansion, we get :

$$
\lim\limits_{h \to 0} h^{\frac{1}{3}} \left(1 - {\frac{1}{3}} h + {\frac{2}{9}} h^{2} - {\frac{14}{81}} h^3 + \cdots \right)
$$,

and this is $0$ as the infinite series converges, because $\left|h\right| < 1$. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: @rstephens0193 No, not L'Hopital. That limit is, by definition of the derivative, the derivative of a certain function at a certain point.

Comment: So the limit given in the answer can be written as :
$$ \lim\limits_{h \to 0} h^{\frac{1}{3}} \frac{(1 + h)^\frac{2}{3} - 1^\frac{2}{3}}{(1 + h) - 1} $$,
which is nothing but $\lim\limits_{h \to 0} h^{\frac{1}{3}} \cdot \frac{d}{dx} (x^{\frac{2}{3}}) \Bigr|_{x=1} $ . Is this what you are saying?